# Continuous Integration Strategy - Project Ref's vs Branching/Merging

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, branching-and-merging

Say you have 7 core projects in a legacy code base (a enterprise API). The code base has roughly 50 applications that reference one or more of the core projects. Only a couple of the 50 applications still work after a vss to tfs migration that was manually don went pear shaped. To get the applications working again many have been taken out of the enterprise API and placed into there own TFS Project.

I am trying to persuade colleagues that they should **not** make a branch of the core projects and put the copy in separate TFS Projects and only merge additions to the core project back into the enterprise API after a release to PROD. Obviously Continous Integration will be much harder when its less frequent.

I am trying to convince colleagues it would be better to take the core projects out of enterprise API and put them in their own TFS Project and then referencing the bin/Debug.

**Is it better to Branch, copy the branch(s) to seperate TFS Projects then Merge (and see conflicts at the end) or is it better to encapsulate core projects and force a team of 20 to use only one copy of each of the core projects?**

Comment: How is this off-topic for SO? I can't imagine this to be a better fit for our programmers sister site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want to have your teams reference already built binaries of the core APIs. The correct granularity of reuse, is the granularity of release (a versioned build) see Robert C Martin's C++ Report from 96 and our explanation here: http://www.urbancode.com/html/resources/articles/reuse-maturity-model.html

Basically, it seems that teams are in a panic and just doing the simplest thing that could get them back and able to deliver. That route is understandable, but I think it is best if they acknowledge that it would be better to have their common libraries as a shared code base and that reusing the code rather than the dlls is bad, and technical debt to be addressed as things stabilize.

Comment: +1 that was the response I was looking for, but the other reply I'm marking as the answer since as its got arguments for and against. Thanks for your time tho, much appreciated.

Comment: I wished I could accept two answers... Someone else upvote this guy, that link is my WMD!

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the maturity of your shared code. I would say there three approaches you can follow, each with its own pros and cons:

Option 1: Directly reference them out of their own Team Project

```
Team Project Application 1
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> Sources
            --> Application 1
                --> Application1.sln

Team Project Application 2
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> Sources
            --> Application 2
                --> Application1.sln

Team Project CoreProject 1
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> Sources
            --> CoreProject1.csproj
```

With this approach, you can set in your CI builds to have all Applications start building once you 've checked in in a CoreProject.
You are bound to have the Team Projects locally mapped with a convention (or else compiling will break)

This is a good approach if you constantly change the CoreProject & need those changes quickly reflected to all impacted Apps.
 It also implies that you can afford instability on a certain App, should a breaking change in a CoreProject inflict it.

Option 2: Indirectly reference them via branching

```
Team Project Application 1
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> SharedSources
            --> CoreProject1_branch
                --> CoreProject1.csproj
        --> Sources
            --> Application 1
                ---> Application1.sln

Team Project Application 2
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> SharedSources
            --> CoreProject1_branch
                --> CoreProject1.csproj
        --> Sources
            --> Application 2
                ---> Application1.sln

Team Project CoreProject 1
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> Sources
            --> CoreProject1.csproj
```

With this approach, each time you have checked in changes in CoreProject1, you need to organize a merge to each affected Application. This poses certain effort, but gives you the time to stabilize the CoreProject on its own playground and then merge it to your Apps.
 This approach implies that you also have a build definition for each CoreProject.
 In general this is a good way to proceed if you value the stability of CoreProject & can't afford to 'contaminate' your Apps should changes cause trouble. This is btw the approach we went for.

Option 3: Make file reference in each application

```
Team Project Application 1
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> SharedBinaries
            --> CoreProject1_branch
                --> CoreProject1.dll
        --> Sources
            --> Application 1
                ---> Application1.sln

Team Project Application 2
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> SharedBinaries
            --> CoreProject1_branch
                --> CoreProject1.dll
        --> Sources
            --> Application 2
                ---> Application1.sln

Team Project CoreProject 1
-->  Development
        --> ...
-->  MAIN
        --> Sources
            --> CoreProject1.csproj
```

With this approach, you 'd need to check in the binary output of a CoreApplication build into each Application.
 This is only recommended if you 're confident that CoreApplication is stable & you wouldn't need to debug it on a regular basis.

Essentially option 2 & option 3 are similar, separated by the well-known debate "project vs. file reference". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973814/project-reference-vs-file-reference) for a SO resource, plenty more can be retrieved via searches.

If your Core Projects are due to constant change and/or have low unit test coverage you should go for option 2 (or 3).
 If you 're confident on their quality, going for option 1 is a good choice, since it will greatly enhance your overall productivity.

Without any knowledge on your products and their quality, simply based on the fairly large numbers you provide (20 people, 50 solutions, 7 core projects), I 'd go for option 2/3.

Another important hint: It happens more than often that shared projectd don't have any means of separated testing. If this is the case and Core Projects have no own unit tests, no dedicated test plan etc, there's no point in doing anything else than option 1.

An additional great resource on the matter is the [work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/06/30/vs-alm-rangers-branching-guidance-shared-code-and-dependency-management.aspx) by the ALM rangers.