# Suppress XML File Generation For 3rd Party DLLs When Building Solution

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, dll, copy-local

Okay, I figured how to disable XML file generation for my own project (Compile -> Generate XML documentation file). There are also some 3rd party DLLs with Copy Local = True, which I need for XCopy deployment. Each of them creates their own XML in the build folder. Is there a way to suppress XML file generation for 3rd party DLLs? I am using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML documentation won't be created for any file referenced DLL's. If there is an XML documentation file for your 3rd party DLL (somehow) in the output folder, then deleting it should remove it permanently.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/973831/229858) for an overview of references in Visual Studio projects.

Comment: For some reason, XMLs are still created in the output folder. Tried cleanup already a dozen of times - same thing. Actually, it's been like that for several years, and only since yesterday that I started digging into it.