# Suppress the creation of xml documentation & resources in 3rd party libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xml-documentation

The same question is already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301941/suppress-xml-file-generation-for-3rd-party-dlls-when-building-solution), however there is no suitable answer, the question's 3 years old and referring to Visual Studio 2010, so I thought I give it a shot.

I've got plenty of 3rd party libraries and frameworks inside a huge project, most of them downloaded via NuGet. Now, a lot of them might have the "Generate XML documentation" flag set because the XML documentation files are being generated over and over again, resulting in a completely cluttered deployment folder. Additionally, 2-3 libraries generate language resources (but they seem to be empty) which results in 20 folders for every language code.

Is there anything I could do about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Project Properties, Build tab, Output section, clear the **XML Documentation** checkbox like this:

[image]