# Setup project: file or project reference for source code of plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reference, setup-project

Let's assume I've three assemblies:

1. `A.dll` has no references.
2. `B.dll` has a file or project reference to `A.dll`.
3. `C.exe` has a project reference to `A.dll` and loads plugin `B.dll` during runtime using reflection.

Up to this point everything works as expected.

Now let's assume I've a setup project for this three assemblies and I want to provide

- the project output / primary output (`A.dll`, `B.dll` and `C.exe`) of all three assemblies
- and the project output / source files (`B.cs` and `B.csproj`) only of the plugin `B.dll`.

If the plugin `B.dll` is using a file reference to `A.dll` and I set a reference path to the installation folder in the `B.csproj` project file then the user, which installed the software, is able to rebuild the `B.dll`.

On the other hand if the plugin `B.dll` is using a project reference to `A.dll` then the user, which installed the software, has to replace the broken project reference with a file reference to `A.dll`.

Normally I prefer using project references in the same solution, see [Project Reference Vs File Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973814/project-reference-vs-file-reference).

So how can I use project references and avoid that the user has to replace the broken project refernces of the plugin `B.dll`?

BTW: I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using project output. Assuming all three go in the Application Folder in the setup project, just drag/drop all three files there from wherever they are, forget project output, and forget (what appears to be) hacking a csproj file.

Comment: @PhilDW: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd(v=vs.100).aspx section `To add the Windows-based application to the installer` point 3 and 4.

Comment: That's an example, not a requirement, I believe Drag and Drop individual files will solve your problem, as in my example here, old but still applies: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/